# Free dynamically allocated memory by Excel XLL when all dependent cells are calculated

Tags: c++, excel, memory-management, xll

My Excel XLL written in C++ exports functions that allocate lots of memory and return references as strings to the allocated data. These references can be passed to other functions as arguments in other cells and eventually a number is produced as a final result.

Is there a way to know when Excel evaluated all dependent formulas so that my XLL can free the memory associated with the given reference? That would allow the users to create bigger spreadsheets because the memory can be freed while worksheet calculations are happening.

There’s xlAutoFree, but it seems to be called just after returning a value, not when all dependent cells finished evaluating.

If that’s not possible, are there any other ways to achieve something similar?

Comment: You could possibly try to hook into the `Application.AfterCalculate` event: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.aftercalculate This is fired when Excel has finished all of its current calculations. Most implementations of this kind of string-based handle keep the memory until Excel is closed, or an explicit ‘delete’ xll function is called. You could try a non-volatile DeleteHandle() xll function which takes as parameters the results of all the calculated cells. Hence this would be the last calculation in the chain.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that AfterCalculate doesn't allow to free the memory while the calculations are still running, but the DeleteHandle() idea is nice and can help by allowing freeing the memory explicitly.
Is there a different way to return handles than just the string-based one?

Comment: Strings are the most common, as they give the user some idea of what the handle might refer to (if you have different types of object). It is popular in implementations to add a version number. Eg ‘ObjectX:0004’, and increment the version number each time the underlying object changes. This lets Excel know that dependant cells need to recalculate.

Comment: Hooking AfterCalculate isn't easy in an XLL as it requires a COM connection, but there is [CalculationEnded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/excel/handling-events) in the XLL interface.  To make all this easier, I'd recommed using an XLL library like [xlOil](https://gitlab.com/stevecu/xloil/) (which I wrote).

Comment: For the problem, can you not have all of your objects hold pointers to their predecessors, then free the list (invalidating your cache strings) when you hit the "final number" - or is there more than 1 endpoint?

Comment: There are potentially more. But thanks for an idea. Its very similar to the DeleteHandle on where the user needs to make sure that it’s called after all the work is done.